# Ubuntu 22.04.3 - VPS Aruba Cloud - Reached target host and network name lookups

Tags: networking, reboot, netplan

I installed a new VPS server with Ubuntu 22.04.3 in ArubaCloud. Evrything was alright. When I sent a apt update /apt upgrade then when I restart the VPS I have the follow problem.

When the system is restarting it stops at: `Reached Target Host and Network Name Lookups` and after you can see `A start job is running for Wait for Network to be Configured` for two minutes. I have read some options related to ipv6 and have made changes, but I can't solve this problem.

When the restart is stopping:

[image: when the restart is stopping]

After, this message:

[image: the second message that you can see]

This is my netplan configuration.

[image: 00-installer-config.yaml]

[image: config.yaml]

If I have to get rid of the ipv6 configuration, I really don't need it.

Comment: Generally this means your netplan has an id that does not exist. I see another issue: AFAIK it should be true and false not 'true' or 'false', Not sure if that is an issue though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+source/systemd/+bug/2036358 for ongoing discussion of recent regressions in the behavior of the `systemd-networkd-wait-online` service.